# Eigenspaces of $s: v_1 \otimes v_2 \mapsto v_2 \otimes v_1 $

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

Consider the linear „swap“ operator $s: v_1 \otimes v_2 \mapsto v_2 \otimes v_1 $, for $v_1 \otimes v_2 \in \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$
I am supposed to show that its eigenspaces are invariant subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n$ under some other linear operator. In the solutions to my exercise they only consider the cases $s v_{\pm}=\pm v_{\pm}$ for $v_{\pm} \in \mathbb{C}^n \otimes \mathbb{C}^n $, so it seems as if the only possible eigenvalues of s are $\pm 1$, could someone maybe explain why that is the case?

Comment: Hint: Decompose the tensor product into the direct sum of symmetric and shew-symmetric tensors.

Comment: Is this how your "swap" operator supposed to act on all [dyads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Dyadic,_outer,_and_tensor_products)?  What if you apply the operator twice? You should be able to make a conclusion about possible eigenvalues now.

Comment: Alternate hint: What happens if you have $s(v_1 \otimes v_2) = \lambda(v_1 \otimes v_2)$ and apply $s$ to both sides?

Comment: Thank you paperskilltrees and Theo, I see your points! One question regarding your way Ted, I think I could decompose an arbitrary tensor $v=v_1 \otimes v_2$ into $v_{++}+v_{+-}+v_{-+}+v_{—}$, where f.e. $v_{+-}=\frac{v_1+v_2}{2}\otimes \frac{v_2-v_1}{2}$ with $v_{++}, v_{—}$ symmetric and $v_{+-}, v_{-+}$ anti-symmetric. Then it becomes clear that $\pm 1$ are EV’s, but why does it follow from here that these are the only options? (Maybe because I now have found 2n independent Eigenvectors and there can’t be more than that?)

Comment: I‘m sorry, only $v_{+-}+v_{-+}$ as a whole is antisymmetric

Comment: If you decompose the whole vector space as a sum of eigenspaces, there can be no more eigenvectors (eigenvalues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $s$ is its own inverse. Let $v$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda$; then $v = s(s(v)) = s (\lambda v) = \lambda^2 v$. Then $v (\lambda^2 - 1) = 0$; therefore, since $v$ is nonzero, we have $\lambda^2 - 1 = 0$ and thus $\lambda = \pm 1$.

In a bit more generality, if $s$ is any linear operator, $P$ is a polynomial, $P(s) = 0$, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue, then $P(\lambda) = 0$. The $P$ in this case is $P(x) = x^2 - 1$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense! :)